# UIRightBarButtonItem setting it's button function. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, segue, uibarbuttonitem

I have the following implemented:

```
UIImage *rightimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"notification-new.png"];
UIBarButtonItem *rightbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:rightimage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:@selector(goNotificationNow)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightbutton ;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Basically, I want the button to push to another ViewController when it is pressed, so I set "goNotificationNow" as :

```
- (void)goNotificationNow
{NotificationsViewController *ok = [[NotificationsViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ok animated:YES];
}
```

Now the button can be pressed but it does not do anything. I must be missing something fundamentally just can't seem to find out what it is. I tried using storyboard as well. and changing the function to:

```
- (void)goNotificationNow
{[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"notifications" sender:self];}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your target is `nil`. You should set it to `self`. The target is the object that will perform the selector call.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the target for the action, in this case you're probably wanting to change `target:nil` to `target:self`.